# Setting local settings fix for function toLocalString()

Tags: javascript, numbers, local, currency, formatting

I format a `number` like this:

```
function pointToComma(number) {
  number = Number(number).toLocaleString();
  return number;
}
```

As w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) states the function `toLocalStrin()` convert a Date object to a string, using locale conventions.

I want to use this function to output the number into a german format. This means commas instead of points for decimals and points to separate thousands. I need the german format in any case. So is there a way to set the local settings fix in that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
.toLocaleString('de-DE')
```

See more [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)